# Archive tar files to a different location in Perl

Tags: perl, file, extract

I am reading a directory having some archive files and uncompressing the archive files one by one.

Everything seems well however the files are getting uncompressed in the folder which has the main perl code module which is running the sub modules.

I want the archive to be generated in the folder I specify.

This is my code:

```
sub ExtractFile
{

 #Read the folder which was copied in the output path recursively and extract if any file is compressed
 my $dirpath = $_[0];

 opendir(D, "$dirpath") || die "Can't open dir $dirpath: $!\n";
 my @list = readdir(D);
 closedir(D);


 foreach my $f (@list) 
 {
  print " \$f = $f";
  if(-f $dirpath."/$f")
  {
   #print " File in  directory $dirpath \n ";#is \$f = $f\n";

   my($file_name, $file_dirname,$filetype)= fileparse($f,qr{\..*});

   #print " \nThe file extension is $filetype";
   #print " \nThe file name is is $file_name";


   # If compressed file then extract the file
   if($filetype eq ".tar" or $filetype eq ".tzr.gz")
   {

    my $arch_file = $dirpath."/$f";
    print "\n file to be extracted is $arch_file";
    my $tar = Archive::Tar->new($arch_file);
    #$tar->extract() or die ("Cannot extract file $arch_file");

    #mkdir($dirpath."/$file_name");
    $tar->extract_file($arch_file,$dirpath."/$file_name" ) or die ("Cannot extract file $arch_file");
   }

  }
  if(-d $dirpath."/$f")
  {
   if($f eq "." or $f eq "..")
   { next; }
   print " Directory\n";# is $f";
   ExtractFile($dirpath."/$f");
  }

 }


}
```

The method ExtractFile is called recursively to loop all the archives.
When using `$tar->extract()` it uncompresses in the folder which calls this method.

When I use `$tar->extract_file($arch_file,$dirpath."/$file_name")` I get an error :

> No such file in archive: '/home/fsang/dante/workspace/output/s.tar' at /home/fsang/dante/lib/Extraction.pm line 80

Please help I have checked that path and input output there is no issue with it.

Seems some usage problem I am not aware of for `$tar->extract_file()`.

Many thanks for anyone resolving this issue.

Regards,
Sakshi

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood `extract_file`.  The first parameter is the name of a file inside the archive to extract.  You're passing in the path of the archive itself.  You passed that to `new`; you don't need to pass it in again.  As the error message explains, `s.tar` does not contain a file named `/home/fsang/dante/workspace/output/s.tar`, so `extract_file` fails.

You can get a list of files in the archive by using `$tar->list_files`.

A simpler solution may be to temporarily chdir to the directory you want to extract the archive into.  [File::pushd](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::pushd) provides an easy way to do that.

Comment: Can you please explain what to pass in the first parameter 
I have also passed the name of the archive file i.e. s.tar but it still says  
No such file in archive: contain a file named /home/fsang/dante/workspace/output/s.tar

Seems it is searching the file in some collection, do I need to add it in some collection property before calling the extract_file method

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi 

Thanks .. now I understand it better and found the solution using File::pushd 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

a typo?

```
$tar->extract_file($arch_file,$dirpath."/$file_name" )
```

should probably be

```
$tar->extract_file($arch_file,$dirpath."/".$file_name)
```

Comment: No, you're the one with the typo.  Your "fixed" line has an odd number of quotes in it.

Comment: thanks @cjm - I forgot the quote at the end of the line - edited

Comment: These two lines are exactly equivalent.  Perl performs variable interpolation on double quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tarFile = "test.tar.gz";
$myTar = Archive::Tar->new($tarFile);
foreach my $member ($myTar->list_files())
{
    my $res = $myTar->extract_file( $member , 'C:/temp/'.$member );
    print "Exract error!\n" unless ($res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a gun being brought to a Swiss Army knife fight. 
Here's a *nix one-liner that does what you want:

```
find /source/dir -name "*.tar" -exec tar -C /target/dir -xvzf '{}' \; -print
```

Is there a need to write a script for this?
You aren't necessarily doing anything special other than debug lines.